# Postgres join to populate newly added column to map table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, inner-join, outer-join

I need a postgres SQL update statement because I am adding a column NAME to DATA_MAP_TABLE and I need to populate it on first run of the update to match the associated values.  Some of the values in DATA_TABLE are unique in their ID and the contents of the BINARY_MESS but have the same NAME Some of them are pointed to by both customer 4 and 5, some are unique to 5 but share a NAME label.  After the new column is populated I will add a not null constraint.  I didn't design this.. I am just trying to implement a solution for updating.. don't shoot me.. any and all help will be GREATLY appreciated!!

```
    DATA_TABLE
    ID NAME DATA
    1  A    <BIN_MESS>
    2  B    <BIN_MESS>
    3  C    <BIN_MESS>
    4  D    <BIN_MESS>
    5  E    <BIN_MESS>
    6  F    <BIN_MESS>
    7  A    <BIN_MESS>
    8  D    <BIN_MESS>

    DATA_MAP_TABLE
    ID  DATA_ID  CUST_ID
    1   1        4
    2   2        4
    3   3        4
    4   4        4
    5   5        4
    6   6        4
    7   1        5
    8   8        5
    9   2        5
    10  7        5
```

Comment: So because I ask a question .. and then realize the answer a few hours later and post it I get downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it just takes seeing it laid out in a hypothetical way to see the solution:

```
ALTER TABLE DATA_MAP_TABLE ADD column name character varying(3);
Update DATA_MAP_TABLE SET name = (
  Select name from DATA_TABLE where DATA_TABLE.id = DATA_MAP_TABLE.DATA_ID;
);
ALTER TABLE DATA_MAP_TABLE ALTER COLUMN "name" SET not null;
```